# Getting timeouts for huge arrays

Tags: ruby

I am taking some sentences in an array and some keywords in queries to check whether the keywords are present in sentences. For small sentences arrays it works fine but for huge array sentences it gets timeout everytime. Any idea on how to optimise this. TIA

```
def textQueries(sentences, queries)
  queries.map { |query|
    index_arr = []
    sentences.map.with_index { |sentence, index|
      sentence_arr = sentence.split(' ')
      if query.split(' ').all? { |qur| sentence_arr.include?(qur) }
        index_arr << index
      end
    }
    index_arr << -1 if index_arr.empty?
    puts index_arr.join " "
  }
end

Example inputs :
**Sentences**:
it go will away
go do art
what to will east
**Queries**
it will
go east will
will

**Expected Result**
0
-1
0 2
```

Comment: Maybe try daru gem? It is built for large scale data analysis

Comment: Can you please some example input and the expected output?

Comment: @spickermann posted example

Comment: `query.split(' ').all? { |qur| sentence_arr.include?(qur) }` means that for each (key)word in `query`, you are executing `sentence_arr.include?(qur)` which in turn traverses `sentence_arr`. Can you think of a solution that traverses `sentence_arr` only once?

Comment: Stefan can you help me out with that.. As i am clueless on how to proceed

Comment: If you're dealing with huge arrays, calling `query.split(' ')` inside a loop is probably a problem. You're splitting that variable once for every time `sentences.map` iterates, and the contents are identical for every iteration

Comment: Tried this but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few optimizations that I see at first glance:

1. You are currently splitting each sentence for every query. Your sample data has 3 sentences and 3 queries. This means each sentence is split 3 times (once of each query). Since the result doesn't depend on the query you should do this up front. Each sentence should only be split once.
2. You are currently using `sentences.map` to iterate sentences, but don't capture the result. You are only using it for iteration purposes and push results to the `index_arr`. [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) creates a new array which you don't use, meaning you are chewing up memory that could be used elsewhere. This could be changed to [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each) which is far more efficient if you don't use the return value.
3. The code `query.split(' ').all? { |qur| sentence_arr.include?(qur) }` isn't really optimal, since it starts searching for a specific word from the front of `sentence_arr` each time. Checking if a certain collection is a subset or superset of another collection is something where [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) often shines.

With all the above in mind something like this should be a lot faster:

```
require 'set'

def text_queries(sentences, queries)
  sentences = sentences.map { |sentence| Set.new(sentence.split(' ')) }

  queries.map do |query|
    query = Set.new(query.split(' '))

    indexes = sentences.each_index.select { |index| sentences[index] >= query }
    indexes << -1 if indexes.empty?

    indexes
  end
end
```

**Note:** If you decide to output the values to the console (like shown in the question):

```
puts indexes.join(' ')
```

Then there is no reason to use `queries.map` since an array with `nil` values will be returned (`puts` always returns `nil`). Change the `map` to `each` in this scenario.